# PyCharm Terminal Error - Command not found

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to run a `.py` file in the PyCharm terminal (macOS).
This file required me to install some dependencies before running, as stated in the readme file I activated a virtual environment and installed these:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
pip install Pillow
pip install pytest-shutil
pip install python-csv
pip install yagmail
```

But whenever I type the command `python3 main.py` (main.py is the file name I want to run) in the terminal I get this error message `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3:  can't open file '/Users/maheshsoni/Downloads/Face-Recognition-Attendance-System-master 2/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

How can I fix this and see the output?

PS-

My virtual environment is activated, this is the entire command line `(env) maheshsoni@Maheshs-MacBook-Air Face-Recognition-Attendance-System-master 2 % python3 main.py`

Comment: On macOS you need to run Python files with `python3 main.py`, assuming the path to your Python installation is in your `$PATH`, which it will be if you've activated the virtual environment first.

Comment: My virtual env is activated and I did the python3 change but now I get the error message stating there is no such file or directory. Does it have anything to do with any permissions?

Comment: Is there a file named `main.py` in that directory?

Comment: This is a GitHub repo that I'm trying to run, and yes there is a main.py file in the repository I have it opened in PyCharm.

Comment: What is the repo? I'd like to try to replicate your problem.

Comment: That will indeed be very helpful, thanks! Here is the link:  [link] (https://github.com/kmhmubin/Face-Recognition-Attendance-System)

Comment: OK, thanks. There is no file named `main.py` in the base of the repo. The directory `FRAS` has one, though, and the directory `Raspberry Pi files` has a file named `Main.py` (note the capitalization, macOS is case-sensitive). Since you're running the program on your Mac, I'd assume `FRAS/main.py` is the file you want to run.

Comment: Right, I did `python3 FRAS/main.py` and I get another error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maheshsoni/Downloads/Face-Recognition-Attendance-System-master 2/FRAS/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Capture_Image
  File "/Users/maheshsoni/Downloads/Face-Recognition-Attendance-System-master 2/FRAS/Capture_Image.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`. I did install opencv in the beginning itself, the python interpreter window includes the opencv-python package.

Comment: I'd suggest switching to the `FRAS` directory first, then running `main.py`. You can also run `pip list` to see which packages you have available.

Comment: Thanks a lot I can see the output now. I created the virtual environment again and did `python3 FRAS/main.py`.